# Javascript conditional table cell formatting failing in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I've got a table in a time reporting application that renders a work group's time for a two week pay cycle before paychecks are cut. Time is reported on a weekly basis and the formatting (red = not yet reviewed) let's a group's approver see which ones have been reviewed vs not at a glance.

The javascript below works like a charm in FF, but not in IE.  Any advice on how to normalize so it'll work in both?

```
function formatTimeTable() {
  var tTables = $(".timeTable");
  var cellLocs = [1, 10]
  for (var a = 0; a < tTables.length; a++) {
    var rows = tTables[a].getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (var b = 1; b < rows.length; b++) {
      var cells = rows[b].getElementsByTagName("td");
      for (var c = 0; c < cellLocs.length; c++) {
        if (cells[cellLocs[c]].innerHTML == "No") {
          for (var d = 0; d <= 7; d++) {
            var curCell = cells[cellLocs[c] + d];
            $(curCell).addClass("redText")
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Here's how the same table renders in both browsers:]

Comment: try using `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`, also in which IE are you trying this code? ~8/9/10/11

Comment: Since you're using jQuery anyway, you could eliminate most of your code with `$(".timeTable td").each()`

Comment: Thanks, Saba.  This is in IE11.  IE9 and 10 render correctly.  Tried textContent in place of innerHTML, but it actually removes all formatting (no red text).